# How can we get the Windows and other software patch level update information

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wmi

How can we get the information of the Windows and other software patch level update using WMI or other Windows API. I got few links but that was for power shell. I need to implement it in VC++ code. please share any link or relevant information related to this.
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve? Do you want to know if Service Pack #x is installed or a list of all installed updates (KBxxxxxxx)?

Comment: @WernerHenze I want to know list of all installed updates(Kbxxxxxx) on machine, and when was last update done.